# Multiple push notifications using ionic push

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

When sending two notifications the second one always overrides the first one in the notification center.
According to the [docs](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-sending-push) this should happen only when using the tag:

> "tag": Indicates whether each notification message results in a new
>   entry on the notification center. If not set, each request creates a
>   new notification. If set, and a notification with the same tag is
>   already being shown, the new notification replaces the existing one.

However this happens to me all the time, regardless whether I set a value for the tag or not.

I even tried setting a random tag & collapse_key (which as far I understand shouldn't be related in this case, but I gave it a try). Still didn't help.
Here's a sample of a notification object I'm sending:

```
{  
   "tokens":[  
      "my-device-token"
   ],
   "profile":"my-profile-tag",
   "notification":{  
      "message":"message",
      "android":{  
         "payload":{  
            "collapse_key":9918519,
            "tag":2825928
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you get any response on this from Ionic? As in their docs they do not mention notId at all.

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this problem.
You need to add "notId" into "data" in "android".
Example:

```
"notification": {
    "title": "testing stack notification ",
    "message":"is it working",
    "android": {               
        "data": {
            "title": "testing stack notification",
            "message": "is it working",
            "style": "inbox",
            "summaryText": "yes its %n% notifications",
            "notId": "123456"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a unique notification id  (unix timestamp for example) in the object in order not to overwrite the previous one - in your case:

```
{  
   "tokens":[  
      "my-device-token"
   ],
   "profile":"my-profile-tag",
   "notification":{  
      "notId": <some-unique-value-here>,
      "message":"message",
      "android":{  
         "payload":{  
            "collapse_key":9918519,
            "tag":2825928
         }
      }
   }
}
```